# Create variable that is 1 if any of chosen variables contain given string in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, apply, grepl

I would like to create variable that is 1 if any of chosen variables start with a given string ("A" in the example) in data.table.

An example with toy data to get the point across:

```
library(data.table)
DT=as.data.table(matrix(c(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 9 )],rep("A",3)), nrow=3, ncol=4))
```

My attempts are to use grepl within an apply within the data.table := command (with a max to pick up the "if any" aspect) to write the new variable. Something like:

```
DT[,letterA:= max(apply(.SD,2,grepl,pattern= "^A" )), .SDcols=c("V1","V2")]
```

but this assigns 1 to all observations if there is an A in the data and I know that this is incorrect since the apply will supply a vector. Also, the "max" way of doing this seems messy. How can I say "if any of these columns starts with A then make the variable letterA a 1 and 0 otherwise"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DT[,letterA:=Reduce("|",lapply(.SD,grepl,pattern= "^A" )), 
            .SDcols=c("V1","V2")]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 letterA
#1:  A  D  G  A    TRUE
#2:  B  E  H  A   FALSE
#3:  C  F  I  A   FALSE
```